# How do I automatise a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a code that copies a row from one sheet to another sheet when the value of a cell is "maybe". I currently have 2 problems:

1. I want to make it automatic, so that every time I add data the other sheet is automatically updated
2. As of now, every time I run the code it starts again from the first row, while I'd need to take into account only new data added

This is the code I came up with:

```
function contact_Maybe () {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Contacts'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('F:F');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('TBC'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in F:F; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Maybe') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,11).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> 1. I want to make it automatic, so that every time I add data the other sheet is automatically updated

Use a trigger. There are simple an installable triggers. Simple triggers use reserved functions names, in this case you might use `onEdit`

```
function onEdit(e){
  /* put here the statements to be executed every time your spreadsheet is edited
     from the Google Sheets User Interface */

}
```

More details on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

> 2. As of now, every time I run the code it starts again from the first row, while I'd need to take into account only new data added

This occurs because is getting the whole F column and iterating over all it's rows.

If you use an on edit trigger, simple or installable, you can use the on edit event object to get the range that was edited. If a single cell is edited you can also get the entered value.

Example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() === 'Contacts') && e.range.columnStart === 6 && e.value === 'Maybe'){
    var ss = e.source;
    var csh = ss.getSheetByName('TBC'); //destination sheet
    var data = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues().flat();
    //Copy data array to destination sheet
    csh.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

More details on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events